# UITextField cuts/hidden from the half first row - until touching

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

I have this really unanswered question.. after looking in the web for this problem i tring my luck with you..
i have a `UITextView` that gets the string from url.
but... the textfield is cuts/hidden fron the half first row and its fixed only when i touch it.

this is the code:

```
- (NSString *)getMonthValues{
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",URL_ADDRESS2,URL_MONTH_ZODIAC]];
            NSString *Value = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
            Value = [Value stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@"\n"];
}

-(void)getMonthValue{
    NSString *horoscope_daily = [self getMonthValues];
    [Month_horoscope setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",horoscope_daily]];
}
```

[image]

can someone please explain this problem and help me fix it ?!

Comment: Completely unrelated but: what font is that?

Comment: Got confused why this is happening.

Comment: Ok first of all this is a UITextView - sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Do you still get the same problem when you initialize `UITextView` with some random text. Ignore URL requests and responses

Comment: good question, when im loading a static text its not showing this problem.

Comment: the only thing i can think off is that the problems is because the text is long.. but how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

It is either 1) covered by other view, or 2) has a frame too small to see the whole text.

1. To check out the cover issue, try setting background property to [UIColor redColor], on all other visible views.
2. And if it is the frame issue, right **after** you setText, issue:

   ```
   [Month_horoscope sizeToFit];
   ```